# What is the proper way to print to user in Java

Tags: java, class, printing, program-entry-point

My computer science teachers have told me that I should not be printing strings from methods such as getters and that I should be printing from the main method to the user. I was wondering if it mattered where I print from and what is the proper way to structure my code.

For example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Bank bank = new Bank(20);
        System.out.println(bank.getBalance());
    }
}

public class Bank {
    int balance;

    public Bank(int balance){
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getBalance(){
        return "You have $" + this.balance;
    }
}
```

as opposed to how my teacher says I should write it

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Bank bank = new Bank(20);
        System.out.println("You have $" + bank.getBalance());
    }
}

public class Bank{
    int balance;

    public Bank(int balance){
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getBalance(){
        return this.balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bracket placement worries me more in terms of program structure than the placement of print statements. That said, it is often okay to print inside getters as long as you remove those print statements from your final program. It is often difficult to tell what's going on inside the getter without writing a print statement inside of it. One way would be to pass a callback interface or null, and it would perform you callback if it's  there, otherwise do nothing, but otherwise you will need to use a debugger to look into the getter to ensure it behaves correctly which is often harder.

Comment: Anyway what your professor is likely unhappy with is that getBalance is intended to return balance, which is suppose to be private, rather than the balance string. If you want to get the balance as a string, simply create another method getBalanceString() which does what you do, while getBalance should just return balance. Also it is likely that balance string should be managed by the main, rather than the bank, since different people using bank might want to display balance differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is right.

You are not really printing anything in your getters, just that you are obscuring the data types. A `balance` of an account (not really a bank) is presumably a numeric type (`int`, `long`) and not a `String`.

In general, let your methods do one thing right. By printing something in your getter and returning is okay for debugging, but not advisable in general. And that's what your teacher means.

Writing classes that have well-defined and type-safe API is useful and important especially in Java.

Comment: 1 & 2 sound like the same point to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is correct.

The purpose of the getBalance method is to "get" the balance in a way that other parts of your application can use it.  There are lots of ways that the balance could be used, including printing it (in various places / various ways) adding it to a spreadsheet, adding it to a total, etcetera.

If you design your `getBalance()` method to just format and print the balance (to standard output), then all of the other things require other methods ... for each other thing.

There is a principle in software engineering known as "[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)".  A class (or more generally, a module) should do the things that it needs to do, and leave the other things to the caller of the classes methods.  In this case, we are talking about SoC at a fine-grained level ... but the principle applies at this level too.

Answer (score 0):

The version your teacher would have you write makes more sense to me. As a user of your Java classes, I prefer getting the balance as a numeric and then use it any way I wish. Presenting the data as a USD string is obviously a valid use case, but not the only one I could think of. Suppose, as a client of your class, that I'd like to know how many euros, pounds or rupees I could get with my account, then the second implementation would suit me better.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is probably suggesting that the Bank should not be responsible for how to display the balance as a string, since different people using the bank may want to display the balance differently.

One way to deal with this is by simply keeping the bank as your professor suggests, and just format it in your own way after you get the balance number.

Second way is to make your own formatter class that formats the string in the way you want like:

```
public class Main2 
{     
    public Main2() {
        Bank bank = new Bank(20);
        System.out.println(BalanceFormat.formatBalance(bank.getBalance()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main2();
    }
}

class Bank {
    private int balance;

    public Bank(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}


class BalanceFormat 
{
    public static String formatBalance(int balance) {
        return ("Your balance is $" + balance);    
    }
}
```

The third way to do this is via callbacks, this way you tell the bank how you want it to behave while it maintains its' defaults.

```
public class Main 
{    
    public Main() 
    {
        Bank bank = new Bank(20);
        System.out.println(bank.getBalanceString());     
        Bank bank2 = new Bank(20, (balance) -> {
            return ("Your balance is: $" + balance);
        });
        System.out.println(bank2.getBalanceString());             
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        new Main();
    }

    private class Bank 
    {
        int balance;
        BalanceStringCallback bankPrintBehavior = null;

        public Bank(int balance, BalanceStringCallback callback) 
        {
            this.bankPrintBehavior = callback;
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public Bank(int balance) 
        {
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public int getBalance() 
        {
            return this.balance;
        }

        public String getBalanceString() 
        {
            if (bankPrintBehavior == null) {
                return String.valueOf(balance);
            } else {
                return (bankPrintBehavior.callback(balance));
            }
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface BalanceStringCallback 
    {
        abstract String callback(int balance);
    }    
}
```

There are other ways, like creating your own subclass of Bank and make it know how to format in the way you like it(Although this makes changing how one bank behaves harder, whereas the third approach of callbacks also allows you to change the behavior on the fly), but those three ways are first that popped to mind.